# TypeScript: error TS2322: Type '{}' is not assignable to type '...'

Tags: typescript

I have an interface:

```
export default interface ValidationResult {
  valid: boolean
  errors?: string[]
}
```

And a function that returns an object implementing that interface:

```
  static validateTitle(title: string): ValidationResult {
    if (title == null || title === '')
      return {valid: false, errors: ["Title can't be empty."]}

    return {valid: true}
  }
```

But when I try to use the first function inside an other function:

```
static async validateMovie(title: string): Promise<ValidationResult> {
    const result = this.validateTitle(title)
    if (result.valid === false)
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { resolve(result) })
    // other validations...
}
```

I get a TypeScript error:

```
error TS2322: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ValidationResult'.
  Property 'valid' is missing in type '{}'.

25       return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { resolve(result) })
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I tried casting with `as ValidationResult` everywhere but without success. What is wrong? I don't understand what TypeScript is complaining about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given your function is already `async` you need just to `return result;`.

Alternatively you can `return new Promise<ValidationResult>`.

Typescript does not infer types for promises yet, and it's a known issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5254

Comment: Yes that was it, thanks. Given that in JavaScript it doesn't make a difference, I never thought of that. It's crazy that the error message is not more explicit for an obvious mistake.

Comment: @vmarquet I also added a link to the github issue on the subject